# how to iteratively print the elements in a SET (STL)

Tags: c++, stl, set

This is the code I have. It is correct.

```
set<float> set1;
set1.insert(1);
set1.insert(2);
set1.insert(3);

set<float>::iterator it1;
for (it1 = set1.begin(); it1 != set1.end(); it1 ++)
{
    cout << *it1 <<" ";
}
```

But why doesn't the following code work?

```
    set<float> set1;
    set1.insert(1);
    set1.insert(2);
    set1.insert(3);

    set<float>::iterator it1;
    for (it1 = set1.begin(); it1 != set1.end()-1; it1 ++)
    {
        cout << *it1 <<" ";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterators of an `std::set` are [*bidirectional*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). That means they support single steps in either direction (`it++`, `it--` etc), but do not support increments of arbitrary length (`it + N` etc).

This is likely because it would be an inefficient O(N) operation, given that `std::set` is usually implemented as a self balancing binary search tree.

You can increment/decrement a bidirectional iterator by an arbitrary amount by using `std::advance`, `std::next` or `std::prev`:

```
std::advance(it, 42);
it = std::next(it, 42);
it = std::prev(it, 42);
```

Comment: what about `vector::iterator`? I thought it were the same. also in the `for`, `it1++' is okay. But the codes prove that I was wrong.

Comment: @tqjustc That is a *random access iterator*.

Comment: @tqjustc No, those are random access ones

Answer (score 1):

`operator-` and `operator+` is not supported for set iterators which are not of random access type, but are bidirectional type.

Ref : [*Here*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set#Member%20types)

Answer (score 1):

The iterator type returned by `set<>::begin()` has no `operator+(int)` specified. However, in your example you can use the `operator--()` instead:

```
for (it1 = set1.begin(); it1 != --set1.end(); ++it1)
{
    cout << *it1 << " ";
}
```

Comment: This code works.but only one best answer can be marked. So I only give you a upvote.